# production.ERROR: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement or after any declare call in the script

Tags: laravel

I have this code in Laravel 5.8

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Report;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Exports\EmployeesGoalPublishedExport;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;

class ExportController extends Controller
{



    public function submitted_goals(){
        return Excel::download(new EmployeesGoalPublishedExport, 'submitted_goals.xlsx');
    }  
}
```

I got this error:

> production.ERROR: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement or after any declare call in the script

How do I get it resolved?

Comment: Check for invisible characters in start of file - also make sure that this is indeed the file that has an error.

Answer (score 0):

Just eliminate the white spaces between php tag and namespace